# What does it mean to constrain a type parameter with `new()`?

Tags: c#, generics, emgucv

Here is a class signature from the popular EmguCV package.  It's the `Image` class - not all of it is important:

```
/// <summary>
/// An Image is a wrapper to IplImage of OpenCV. 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TColor">Color type of this image (either Gray, Bgr, Bgra, Hsv, Hls, Lab, Luv, Xyz, Ycc, Rgb or Rbga)</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TDepth">Depth of this image (either Byte, SByte, Single, double, UInt16, Int16 or Int32)</typeparam>
public partial class Image<TColor, TDepth>
  : CvArray<TDepth>, IImage, IEquatable<Image<TColor, TDepth>>
  where TColor : struct, IColor
  where TDepth : new()
```

Specifically, note

```
  ...
  where TDepth : new()  // <-- either Byte, SByte, Single, double, UInt16, Int16 or Int32
```

**How does `new()` constrain the type parameter `TDepth` to the .NET integral types?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't.  All `new()` guarantees is that the generic type with the constraint (in this case `TDepth`) MUST provide a parameterless constructor and that it is not abstract, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean `Image` must provide a parameterless constructor, or `TDepth`?

Comment: `TDepth`.  I updated my answer to avoid any confusion :)